# Pressurizing with nitrogen vs vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, vacuum, chemical-compounds, polymers

pressurizing with vacuum causes volatilization of liquid.

Comment: "vacuum, at the same pressure"  I'm not sure what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the process instructions call for 35-50 psi of pressure with an inert atmosphere (N2 or CO2) seriously implies that there is a real possibility of vaporization of some of the monomer during the casting process.  The existing process instructions were no doubt developed in a laboratory where the various process variables were manipulated such that the desired product was made to meet very specific process specifications.  Running your process under a vacuum when the instructions call for a pressurized autoclave is probably going to leave you with a finished product which does not have the final specifications that you are looking for.

Comment: And it may leave you with a mess that's very hard to scrape off the walls of the autoclave. :)